# Attach active storage file to mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, rails-activestorage

I have tried everything and still can't get this to work.

I have two types of application in my system that are pre-qualified and sent to lenders,

1) one generates a pdf
2) second should use active storage attachments and attach them to an ActionMailer

First one is working the second is giving me the following error:

> [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [905177a5-b0e9-46f4-ba9a-fc4630e873f9]
>   Error performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID:
>   905177a5-b0e9-46f4-ba9a-fc4630e873f9) from Async(mailers) in 140.14ms:
>   Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   https://funderhunt.co/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBZ1lIIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--fa91a15681c23d47d767169c7821601aa15ed2b3/Statuses.pages?disposition=attachment):

The link is correct tho:

My mailer code for this part looks like this:

```
      q = 0
      statement.files.each do |file|
        q += 1
        bank_statement = File.read(rails_blob_url(file, disposition: "attachment"))
        attachments["statement_#{q}.pdf"] = { :mime_type => 'application/pdf', :content => bank_statement }
      end
```

What is wrong? Can you please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `File.read` expects a local file, not a URL.

Answer (score 17):

If somebody lands here looking for a general solution:

```
modelname.attachments.each do |file|
  attachments[file.blob.filename.to_s] = {
    mime_type: file.blob.content_type,
    content: file.blob.download
  }
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do something like,

```
statement.files.each_with_index do |file, q|
  attachments["statement_#{q + 1}.pdf"] = { mime_type: 'application/pdf', content: file.blob.download }
end
```

`file.blob.download` will return the content of the file, similar to `File.read`.

Comment: Hi thanks, yes I did the same right before, however, how does it affect memory? Will the system store that file in cache or tmp? How can I delete them afterward?

Comment: `Blob#download` gets read into memory and then later collected by Ruby's GC. If you pass a block to `Blob#download` it will streamed and yielded in chunks.